# How to convert weeks to Month in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have data that consists of dates,which makes it ti Week Number, I want to write sql synatx saying week1-week4/5 depending on how many days we have in that month.

```
  Week Number | Month
    Week 1|  Jan
    Week 2|  Jan
    Week 3|  Jan
   Week 4 |  Jan
   Week 5 | Jan 
   Week 6 | Feb
   Week 7 | Feb
 Week 8   | Feb
   Week 9 | Feb
```

Henceforth list goes until 52 weeks of the year, what syntax query to make these weeks into Month ? How can I get this Month column in my output instead of week.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using MySQL you can use MONTH(Datecol) or EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Datecol)

```
    Select [Week of],
           [Week Number],
           MONTH([Week of])
    From DataTable
```

or

```
Select [Week of],
       [Week Number],
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM [week of])
From DataTable
```

Comment: Its MYSQL syntax, but I dont get this @ Kelevra.                                                         My excel has SHip fiscal week Number from 1 to 52, how can I convert them into month.

Comment: @S.Y.K.J based on what date your excel calculates the week number? in the sample data you specified the date, so I assumed that based on that date you get the week

Comment: @Kelevra, No My excel has only week Number. so its week 1 to week 52. What shall be my SQL query to convert these weeks to Months. eg week 1-week 5 = January,Week 6-9 as Feburary.

Comment: So where do you get column [Week Of]? and is it related to [Week Number]?

Comment: You have a table of dates. There should be a date that drives the week number, thus will be driving the month. SQL can't convert weeks to month because each year months will have different week numbers. So you need to take different approach. Usually when people build Data Warehouse they create a Calendar table where each day will have a week number, month, year, holiday etc.

Comment: @Kelevera, week of was manually added to the excel, and its uniform each year. Do we not have anything to convert by Fiscal week Number to Month.

Comment: you should've started from there. Edit your sample data in your question for just weeks and no date. Also this might be helpful https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128941/how-to-get-month-name-from-week-number-and-year

Comment: I did not understand, can you please give me sql query to convert these weeks to Month.